# Возврат во вкладку для web notification

Tags: javascript

По определенным событиям создается уведомление в браузер. И вызывается следующим образом:

```
// ...
var Notification = new Notification(title, body)
// ...
```

Пользователю всплывает уведомление и все хорошо. Но необходимо сделать, что бы по нажатию на это уведомление он возвращался на вкладку, которая отправила ему его. Как это можно реализовать на JavaScript?
Подключение сторонних библиотек крайне нежелателен (JQuery уже есть).

Comment: Что значит вкладка которая отправила ему?

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как это можно сделать.

Допустим у нас есть две страницы к примеру `www.example.com/prev` и `www.example.com/next`.

Просто для примера в `prev` странице добавим скрипт который по определенному клику или каким то другим образом открывает страницу `next` с параметром `_blank` (параметр можно изменить, не в этом суть).

```
function open_next(){
    window.open("www.example.com/next",'_blank');
}
```

А в странице `next` например есть кнопка при клике на которую нужно вернуться на страницу которая открыла `next`.

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

А это `javascript` которая возвратит нас на страницу `prev` после клика на кнопку.

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
    close();
}
```

Подробно о [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

А здесь про [close](http://javascript.ru/window.close)